# SQL Server 2008 r2 or PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I am rewriting an application for my company which requires a database.  We are currently using SQL Server 8 and I will be updating the database.  My question is which database to use.  I have been looking at both SQL Server 2008 r2 and PostgreSQL 9.

The database will be hosted on a Windows Server 2008 box and will be used for both the stand-alone app and an associated website written in .NET.

Some of my points of concern are:

1. Cost (obviously PostgreSQL wins out here).
2. Is it ready for primetime?  I have read somethings about it being as good as SQL but would like some input from those using it.
3. Ease of use.  I am very comfortable with SQL Server.  I have been experimenting with PostgreSQL and while it is different than SQL Server I am getting the hang of it.
4. Speed.  Is PostgreSQL as fast as SQL Server?
5. Can I use ADO.NET (.NET 4.0) with PostgreSQL and get the same functionality as Using SQL Server (will be using Linq or Entity Framework)?

I will NOT be converting our old database in SQL Server 8 to the new database so I am not concerned with any conversion.

I would be interested in peoples opinion of the two and if PostgreSQL is an acceptable solution for a business application given the above.

TIA

Brian

Comment: This might be interesting: http://datachomp.com/archives/top-10-reasons-i-like-postgres-over-sql-server/ and this: http://datachomp.com/archives/im-leaving-sql-server-for-postgres/

Comment: The sql server is great but it's expensive. The situation that's easy to fall into is this: sql server express is free, let's use it. Then you write a lot of code, your app grows and you realize express isn't enough. Then you realize that some of your clients can't afford to buy it either. That's pretty much a dead end: you either have to rewrite the entire thing or buy it. That's why I'd recommend to choose PostgreSQL (although I haven't touched it at all).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This really depends on your DB size and your comfort zone.

SQL Server Express edition is a fully functional *free* database up to 4GB in size; perfectly adequate for most small to mid-sized apps. (aside - IMHO, MS Licensing was the best thing ever to happen to the open source community!!)

PostgreSQL is a fully functional, free database w/o the 4Gb limitation - however, PostgreSQL follows the Oracle style of SQL and database management. If you're not familiar with that, you can run into some gotchas.

Throwing Dot Net into the mix adds a not insignificant wrinkle.

1. Can you use .Net with PostgreSQL? Yes, but Dot Net will work better with SQL Server.
2. Are you comfortable writing complex ODBC interface code? If yes, PostgreSQL remains a contender. If not, you'll be better off with SQL Server.

#### 3rd party edit

The last points regarding Dot Net are no longer the case

There are [different options to connect to  PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/download/products/2-drivers-and-interfaces/). For Ado.Net

- dotConnect
- SQL Relay
- Npgsql

Comment: +1 for mentioning about Express Edition. Another issue is with procedural languages and additional learning curve (T-SQL, PL/pgSQL or something else like PL/Python are incompatible).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.  Sticking with SQL Server was what I figured would be needed as I am developing with C# and need the ADO features.

Comment: For the record, there's no need to write "complex ODBC interface code". Instead, you can be sensible and use an ADO.NET provider for PostgreSQL - http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/ While I'm all about SQL Server, part of this answer is just plain wrong.

Comment: See @Kenanaih's comment below - PostgreSQL and MS database interface frameworks don't work together all that well. If you're going to go that route, you're probably going to need to do some (if not much) of your own ODBC coding.

Comment: Also, for the record, ADO.NET and EF are worlds different; coding for one is not at all like coding for the other.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 r2 Express has a DB size limit of 10 GB

Comment: agree with Jeremiah, there's plenty of ORMs and plain SQL works just fine with ADO, theres a ton of drivers out there for every conceivable programming platform, Java/.NET/python etc. No reason not to use Postgres

Comment: I would also add that Sql Server Express will only utilize one core. That may become bottleneck even before 10 Gb limit is reached.

Answer (score 30):

As pointed out by SteveG, SQL-Server Express is probably what you want.

But I've used SQL-Server, SQL-Server Express and PostgreSQL extensively, and you should be aware that SQL-Server Express has some more nasty limitations other than just the DB size:

- Installation requires **administrator privileges** (**and system restart** - **bad if you want to run integration tests against specific versions of the database**, or have an application that needs to run **without** requiring admin-rights)
- ReportingService Express can only connect to a local database,
- ReportingService Express cannot use other data-sources than the local sql server (no ODBC)
- Some ReportingServices features are missing (e.g. graphs and CSV/XML export formats)
- **Constrained to the usage of 1GB RAM** (Same in 2008/2012)
- **Constrained to a single CPU**  (newspeak: Limited to the lesser of 1 Socket or 4 cores)
- **no Row-Level-Security;** only in Standard and Enterprise edition (even standard edition has limitations)
- no table and index partitioning
- no indexed views
- no database mirroring
- no database tuning advisor
- no notification services
- cannot send email (you might be able to do it using CLR-Stored procedures if you absolutely need to)
- cannot use/call Web-Services (newspeak: **no HTTP-Endpoints**)
- no service broker
- no fulltext and no semantic search (**must be installed** - requires Express Advanced Services)
- Profiler tool is not included with SQL Server Express editions. (there is [SQL Express profiler](https://github.com/ststeiger/ExpressProfiler) on github)
- Job Scheduling service is not available with SQL Server Express.
- Data import and export feature is not available with SQL Server Express (**must be installed**)
- does not come with SSIS

and as said
- 4GB database size (raised to 10GB in SQL 2008 R2 and SQL 2012)

**Note that the limit of 10GB is neither 10GB nor 10 GiB (10 * 1024<sup>3</sup>), it's actually 10'240 MB (10 * 1'024 MB), which is actually only 95% of the 10 GB that I'd have interpreted as 10GiB (10'240'000'000*100/10'737'418'240)**

Add to this the limitation that Microsoft-SQL-Server will only ever run on Windows (to date, Linux-port of SQL-server is now coming, but only as CTP so far, and without BI).

So to the other points often overlooked:

- In Windows 7, you can only have up to 20 concurrent connections but no more. 
  If you need more, you'll have to put your SQL Server installation onto a Windows Server OS.
  That means if you use SQL-Server Express in a use case with more than 20 concurrent users, you'll still need a windows server license (the number of connections is not related to SQL Server edition, but to the operating system). You'll probably hit the 1GB RAM barrier before as bottleneck.
- If you want to economize, you'll have to run the db engine on the same server as the web server, with all resulting performance penalties.

So now to your points (in order of importance)
5. Yes, there is Npgsql.dll (MIT license), so there is no need for ODBC
BUT: If your code uses System.Data.SqlClient everywhere (e.g. parameters, especially when copy-pasted all over the code) then you will have to re-write more than just the SQL code (Use the abstract classes in System.Data.Common instead, or or the System.Data.IDB* interfaces).

If your code copy-pastes SqlClient everywhere, it could be argued that it needs rewriting anyway.

3. Ease of use: 
   A little more of a learning curve than SQL-Server, but overall, not too different.
   pgAdmin may not fullfill your requirements if you're used to SSMS, but there are several other management & development tools you can use (e.g. Navicat) that come very close to SSMS or even top it.

4.Speed. Is PostgreSQL as fast as SQL Server?
Yes and no. It can actually be faster. Granted, because SQL-Server has had much work done on the query optimizer, PostgreSQL might be a little slower when compared to the Enterprise Ultimate version of SQL-Server (or whatever the current name of the killer-edition is).
But, who ever has that version ? If you can use all your CPUs with all cores and all the RAM you want with PostgreSQL, you will always be faster than some cut-down Express or Standard version of SQL-Server with 1 CPU and 1 to a few GB of RAM (windows limits you to 64GB in 64-Bit afaik, with Linux you can exceed the 4 GB RAM per application limit even on a 32 bit processor with the bigmem kernel and can get it to address 64 GB RAM on a 32 bit processor, not to mention the 64-Bit limits), no matter how super-over-optimized the query optimizer is on SQL-Server. That said, my personal opinion from using both pg and ms is that PostgreSql has the better query optimizer, but that's just my opinion, I have no data to back that up. Besides, windows (Windows 7) is a slow operating system (again personal opinion, no data to back it up). So when you can let PG run on Linux in headless mode, it will almost certainly be faster than SQL-Server, even the enterprise ultimate edition.

Memory footprint
You can totally configure PostgreSQL. You are in charge of the configuration file.
Can be small or large depending on how you adjust your settings. The overall PG memory footprint to achive the same as SQL-Server on Windows at comparative speed will be quite a bit lower, this is especially true when you run it in headless mode on Linux (no server GUI).

Cost
Yes, quite obviously PostgreSQL wins out here.
Do not forget: It's not just the Server licensing costs we talk about, but also the operating system, and remote access (e.g. additional very expensive Citrix licenses on Windows compared to free SSH access on Linux).
And the other thing: PostgreSQL is OpenSource and Free. If you compare it to SQL-Server, you should not compare it to the Ultimate Enterprise Edition of SQL server (and windows server), but with the version you could actually afford. PostgreSQL however will always be the one free ultimate all-inclusive all-free all-opensource BSD license edition. If you compare the features of PostgreSQL to the Sql-Server Ultimate Enterprise Edition, you'll also have to compare the costs to the ultimate enterprise edition as well (and in 99% of cases, you'll find it not worth the price).



2. Is it ready for primetime? 
Yes actually Skype and WhatsApp run their database on PostgreSQL. 
You'll find it has some problems (bad error messages - connection disconnected) when you try to run a 50+ MB insert scripts, but Microsoft's SSMS crashes long before that amount.

Summa summarum, PG probably is more ready for PrimeTime than SQL-Server.

- PG has has had paging for almost 10 years now (MySQL as well as SQL-Standard syntax compliant) , SQL server just got that feature with SQL-2012, only standard-compliant.
- You can simply xcopy deploy PostgreSQL, works perfectly without admin rights
- PG has XML support, just like SQL-Server (and also, on PG you can actually use xml-functions in computed column definitions - not so in sql-server of any edition)
- PG has JSON support, SQL Server? I believe they are still fully invested in thinking that XML is the future - and purposely crippling the web as a platform. (they are adding JSON support now for SQL-Server 2016 CTP, but it stores data as nvarchar, so you won't be able to set (fulltext) indices on specific JSON-fields like you can on PostgreSQL)
- PG has HSTORE support (associative array column), SQL-Server doesn't
- PG has array columns. Arrays are a core part of programming, except in SQL Server, where they don't exist (try parametrize an IN-clause or filter a cyclic-recursion)...
- PG has had spatial support for a long time, SQL-Server's spatial support is relatively new and relies on .NET extensions and is object-oriented (hello RELATIONAL database? )
- PG has the better and faster fulltext search (personal opinion, not backed up by data because it's as clear as it's clear that Google-Chrome is faster than IE 8)
- PG has companies offering commercial support, just like Microsoft does for SQL-Server; the advantage is that you actually get your bugs/feature-requests fixed for your money on PG support. You probably know Microsoft support, so I'll spare you any further rants of mine ...
- PG has IPv6 support, Microsoft ?
- PG performs normal under heavy load, with SQL-Server on Windows we've had some strange issues that appear and disappear at random (Heisenbugs ?).
- SQL Server still to this day deploys pessimistic concurrency out of the box, PG doesn't
- Compression out of the box. In SQL Server, compression is an "Enterprise Edition+" feature which means you are spending the cost of at least 1 dev in order to get the ability to use compression. Once you have paid for that ability, you still have to figure out how to implement it. Postgres does this for you out of the box, automatically and for free.
- Concurrent Index Creation. This yet another feature that SQL Server is capable of doing, but only if you are able to afford Enterprise Edition. Postgres has your back on this and you can leave your wallet at home.
- Indexable functions – sargability. In Postgres, you can actually index certain functions and maintain sargability. With SQL Server, BOOM - table scans - adios performance
- PG employs Unicode (UTF8) by default. No longer can an incompetent predecessor cripple the entire application with horrible varchar and missing N' for string datatype like they do in SQL Server. The N' syntax still works though, so no compatibility problems if you use them.
- PG supports [recursive cascaded deletes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762670/sql-server-cascading-delete-with-recursive-foreign-keys/32138389#32138389), SQL server doesn't support that at all (though it actively tells you when you want to put the cascade on the referential constraint)
- PG supports [GREATEST(value [, ...]), LEAST(value [, ...])](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#AEN15582)
  Microsoft: `CASE WHEN HugeExp1 > HugeExp2 THEN HugeExp1 ELSE HugeExp2 END)` ...    
  `CASE WHEN N > 2 THEN 'ROYALLY SCREWED'` ... 
  or this very maintainable gem
  `SELECT  ( SELECT MIN(Price)  FROM  ( VALUES (123),(456) ) AS AllPrices(Price) )`
- PG supports UTF-8 CSV files since ever, SQL server doesn't support UTF-8 CSV files prior to SQL-Server 2014 SP2 (try import the MaxMind GeoIP database - you need to write your own program for SQL-server...).

Drawbacks of PG:

- Windows version ain't as stable & fast as the Linux version
- No free BI-tool like SQL-Server-Reporting-Services (ok there  is Eclipse BIRT, but it runs on JAVA). 
  On the other hand, for a bit of money you can get stimulsoft reports, which has more export formats than SSRS, and actually renders fine in browsers other than IE as well as IE > 8, unlike SSRS (2005 - 2012 so far, and so far I read SSRS 2014 is no different than 2012).

That said, if your only problem is fulltext-search with SQL-Server Express, you should take a look at Lucene.NET (Apache License).

Also, be careful if you're thinking about using SQL-Express in production:

> So far we’ve considered only a few of the most obvious limitations,
> but the point is that what seemed like a great idea driven by the
> thought of considerable cost savings could end up being an absolute
> disaster for your business. Worse, any initial cost savings you gained
> from using a free product could be easily negated down the road by the
> cost of disaster recovery and the damage to your business’ reputation
> while an important database is down. So needless to say, despite the
> appeal of its zero dollar price tag, SQL Server Express is definitely
> not the right database solution to power your business.

[Source: bitwizards.com](https://bitwizards.com/Thought-Leadership/Blog/2016/April/The-Perils-of-Running-SQL-Server-Express-in-a-Prod)

Comment: I have to say you're coming across a little biased. I've also used Pgsql and SS for years (although admittedly the "Enterprise Ultimate" version of MSSQL) and have to say that P has consistently caused me more headaches. In M the only thing I have to worry about is good disk I/O and sensible schemas/indices. In P I end up wading through config setting to work out why it's being slow _this_ time. I just want something that works and lets me get on with other stuff. Also, comparing to Express is unfair. It's not meant as a fully fledged competitor, it's a lightweight Db which is often embedded.

Comment: @Basic: Actually, Express is meant for those that can't afford or don't need any of the higher versions, like students, startups, small corporations. The embedded version is SQL CE, not Express. Also, PG comes with very very conservative configs (lowest common denominator). The config is not adjusted to your specific system. You can however run pgtune -i postgresql.conf -o postgresql-tuned.conf, that will take care of these issues automagically. Then there's an entire page dedicated to tuning in the wiki: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization .

Comment: You got me on CE, sorry. I was tired and mis-thought. As to tuning, pgtune is nowhere near sufficient to make it perform in Enterprise-scale. I've got a system at the moment running on a [Fat Twin](http://www.supermicro.co.uk/products/nfo/FatTwin.cfm) that struggles to do more than about 300 updates/second on a 9M record table (Postgres XC on 4 nodes, disks in RAID 10, 512GB Ram). Having wasted a week trying to tune it, then getting a consultant in to tune it, we're still not getting anything like from MSSQL (850+/s). I'm not saying it's no good for some scenarios but definitely not all.

Comment: Oh and before you get insulting, try to remember you're supposed to be a professional (or at least act like one on this site). Disagreeing with you is not a personal attack. It's a pity you're incapable of understanding that.

Comment: @Basic: Where did you see a personal attack ? I might have implied that you have not done your homework, but obviously, you have a little more complex system than I thought. 600 vs. 300 seems like an awfully large difference. Are you positive your problem is not related to an ORM framework, like Entity, or data compression ?

Comment: And likewise, sorry for the snark. Late/tired. It's not worth diving into here but the problem mentioned above is due to being I/O bound (in both cases). It looks like MSSQL is doing something clever (maybe batching writes?). At the very least, it's seeking less on the disks for the same operations. Interesting suggestion re: compression (TOAST, right?) that sounds like a possible culprit. I've got excess storage, it's the perf. I need. On the bright side, it means I get to play with some Fusion IO cards as a stop-gap, so there's an upside to everything. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: And here it is another biased writing about how P is better than M. Yeah yeah sure. I can't understand why you people being such a fanboy of such things. Both of them have their own advantages/drawbacks. You only listed P's advantages over M. M has tons of it's advantageous too.

Comment: System Restart ???? As for "administrator privileges" are you confusing the UAC dialog for actual administrator requirements? The services run under a low-privilege account

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: No i mean you must install SQL-Server express before you can use it. You can't just xcopy-deploy it. It thus requires admin-rights. This is important if you ship an application that is supposed to run without admin rights (no installation).

Comment: And PostgreSQL just allows copy pasting the binaries without requiring permissions or without protecting its critical files? No `sudo` required?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: Actually, yes. It allows it. You can download the zip from the dowload-page, unzip it, issue the initdb and createdb directive, and start-stop the database. Everything works as standard-user. You can even xcopy postgis3. Unlike SQL-Server. You can of course also download the installer and install it as a service. BUT: that is not required. And actually on Windows, so no sudo there. Of course, that means it must be unzipped somewhere where the user has write-rights. This is particularly useful if you don't have admin rights on your windows machine.

Comment: Actually *NO* because then you'd end up with unprotected binaries that a bad installer or application can corrupt. That's the reason Linux, MacOS and Windows require user confirmation. And NO, a download doesn't mean the database won't end up running with your own account's administration privileges. You'd need to manually create service accounts and folders with the correct permissions to ensure the database is safe (from a reliability and security perspective)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: Actually YES. It works ony my machine. Do I need to send you the screenshot ? And no, the account has no admin rights, and there is no need for user confirmation. And that means you can "install" postgresql without admin rights. You need admin rights to install sql-server express. Which is bad. That means you can't xcopy deploy your application if you use sql-server-express. Security is another matter. I need it for development. Integration tests.

Answer (score 4):

From my own personal experience, I find that PostgreSQL runs better on a linux box - lose the windows OS. I'm not very familiar with SQL Server, but I have had no issues with speed or flexibility in working with Postgres. While I can't speak to ADO.NET, I have had much success with using Postgres in the real world (under constant load). In your case, the only variable I could see is integration with ADO.NET. http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/ may be a starting point.

Answer (score 4):

As some mentioned above, this really relies on how big your DB will have to be.

Especially the difference price of a CPU-core vs the price of the licence for that core is really heavy.
CPU costs nothing in this comparision.
So if you need 16+ Cores, i would give Postgres a chance.
you will be able to buy a lot more cores for your Postgres server with the saved money.

I am Software developer, and the customers we have, have to pay much more for the Sql Server License than for all the other things together: softwaredevelopment, Clienthardware, Serverhardware, DB-Administration and so on.

Most of the time its cheaper, to buy new hardware, than to optimize your code.
But thats not true for the SQL Server CPU.

(however, you can still invest in Ram/HDDs without raising license costs)

Comment: +1 I agree with "pay much more for the Sql Server License than for all the other things together", and "Most of the time its cheaper, to buy new hardware, than to optimize your code".

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried using PostgreSQL with ADO.NET, but from my experience using it with MySQL, you might be better off sticking with SQL Server if you plan to use LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework.

While there are probably third party libraries that will allow you to integrate those technologies with PostreSQL, I think you'll find that things will go a lot smoother with SQL Server.  Pretty much all the nice tools built into Visual Studio that make those technologies so easy to work with will only work with SQL Server.

Comment: Many of the features can be made to work with external tools and software, but microsoft really doesn't want people doing that.

Comment: @Sqeaky Or more to the point, nobody is willing to spend the time to get the tools working so well with other databases. Don't blame MS for not investing time in supporting [arbitrary technology you like]. Add the support yourself. Isn't that's what's so wonderful about being outside the Microsoft ecosystem?

Comment: @basic I meant exactly what I said. microsoft wants businesses and individuals to buy their "whole stack" and is doesn't want compatibility to exist in many, but not all, situations.